# Properly using parameterized Factory.Create() method using DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mvp, factory-method, ninject

My factory is using method injection because I thought this was the best way to make it so far. Besides, I doubt it is a good thing after having to call on its `Create` method from within a dependent object.

The only way I might think of whilst continuing to use the parameterized factory `Create` method, is to inject the dependencies directly in the `MainPresenter` so that it may provide with the dependencies to the method, and I dislike it. It dislike it because it is not the `MainPresenter` that depends on the `ICustomerManagementView` and the `ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory`, it's its dependency. So I would feel like I'm sabotaging my own code by doing so.

**MainPresenter**

```
public class MainPresenter : Presenter<IMainView>, IMainViewUiHandler {
    public MainPresenter(IMainView view
        , ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory customerManagementFactory) 
        : base(view) {
        this.customerManagementPresenterFactory = customerManagementPresenterFactory;
    }

    public void ManageCustomers() {
        // The following line is causing trouble.
        // As you can see per the ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory code sample,
        // the Create() method takes two parameters: 
        //   1. ICustomerManagementView, and
        //   2. ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory 
        // Hence I have to provide the dependencies manually, I guess. Which is
        // something to avoid at any cost.            
        var customerManagementPresenter = customerManagementPresenterFactory.Create();
        customerManagementPresenter.ShowView();
    }
}
```

**ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory**

```
public interface ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory {
    // Here. Though I ask Ninject to inject my dependencies, I need to
    // provide values to the parameters when calling the method from within
    // the MainPresenter class. The compiler won't let me do otherwise! And
    // this makes sense!...
    [Inject]
    CustomerManagementPresenter Create(ICustomerManagementView view
                                     , ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory factory);
}
```

**IMainView**

```
public interface IMainView : IView, IHasUiHandler<IMainViewUiHandler> {
}
```

**IMainViewUiHandler**

```
public interface IMainViewUiHandler : IUiHandler {
    void ManageCustomers();
}
```

**IUiHandler**

```
public interface IUiHandler { 
}
```

**IHasUiHandler**

```
public interface IHasUiHandler<H> where H : IUiHandler {
    H Handler { set; }
}
```

**MainForm**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMainView {
    public MainForm() { InitializeComponent(); }

    public IMainViewUiHandler Handler { private get { return handler; } set { setHandler(value); } }
}
```

**CompositionRoot**

```
public class CompositionRoot {
    private CompositionRoot() { }

    public static IKernel BuildObjectGraph() {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        BindFactories(kernel);
        BindViews(kernel);
    }

    private static void BindFactories(IKernel kernel) {
        kernel.Bind(services => services
            .From(AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                .GetAssemblies()
                .Where(a => !a.FullName.Contains("Tests")))
            .SelectAllInterfaces()
            .EndingWith("Factory")
            .BindToFactory()
        );
    }

    private static void BindViews(IKernel kernel) {
        kernel.Bind(services => services
            .From(AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                .GetAssemblies()
                .Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("Windows")
                         && !a.FullName.Contains("Tests"))
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .EndingWith("Form")
            .BindSelection((type, baseType) => type
                .GetInterfaces()
                .Where(iface => iface.Name.EndsWith("View"))
            )
        );
    }
}
```

So I wonder, is it best to implement the `ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory` and bind the implementer with it within my `CompositionRoot`, so that I could provide those dependencies through constructor injection to the `Create` method which shall no longer take any arguments, or shall I make it otherwise?

What I like of writing a simple interface is that Ninject does it all for me to a factory, and no code is necessary to build an instance of the desired type. Besides, when the constructor of the class to be created uses constructor injection, it seems like it is impossible to have a simple factory interface bound as a factory, and one need to implement the factory interface by hand.

What did I get right/wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, no need for parameterized `Factory.Create` method as per this answer:

[**Properly using parameterized Factory.Create() method using DI**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25780183/162167).

In short, because Ninject knows how to resolve your returned type, and also your parameterized types, Ninject shall inject whatever needed to instantiate your class.

```
public class CustomerManagementPresenter : Presenter<ICustomerManagementView> {
    public CustomerManagementPrenseter(ICustomerManagementView view
        , ICustomerDetailPrensterFactory factory)
        : base(view) {
        customerDetailPresenterFactory = factory;
    }

    public void ShowDetailsFor(Customer customer) {
        var detailPresenter = customerDetailPresenterFactory.Create();
        detailPresenter.ShowDetailsFor(customer);
    }

    private readonly ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory customerDetailPresenterFactory;
}
```

And because both `ICustomerManagementView` and `ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory` are known to Ninject, a simple `ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory` looks like this:

```
public interface ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory { 
    CustomerDetailPresenterFactory Create();
}
```

And when the `Create` method is called, Ninject will know it has to instantiate everything necessary to have a consistent instance of `CustomerDetailPresenter`, so it will:

1. Instantiate an `ICustomerDetailView` to whatever it is bound in your `CompositionRoot`
2. Instantiate an `ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory` using its [**Factory Extension**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/)
3. Then finally instantiate your `CustomerDetailPresenter` class so that you may work with just like if you would have instantiated it yourself.

Besides, the `ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory` need to be bound using either two methods:

> 1. Using convention binding

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind(services => services
    From(GetProjectAssemblies())
    .SelectAllInterfaces()
    .EndingWith("Factory")
    .BindToFactory());
```

> 2. Using per-factory binding

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory>().ToFactory();
kernel.Bind<ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory>().ToFactory();
...
```

It's as simple as that!